# Help on Crunch Wordlist Creating

Tags: password, kali

I would like to receive some help on making a crunch wordlist. Can anyone give me the command for a 8 character password, the first 4 characters being letters and the last 4 characters being numbers. No special characters. Please explain the command after listing, this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are you using it for? A school assignment? A corporate security demonstration?

Comment: The reasons do not matter. My real reason is for personal use. I would be greatful if you provided the command.

Comment: The reasons matter to me, and you are asking for my help. I only support ethical hacking, so I will not help you unless you can explain exactly what it's for. I will not be an accessory to illegal or criminal activities.

Comment: Might as well. I don't understand how Crunch works and I simply needed an explanation for wordlist creating. The example I created would teach all I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

```bsh
crunch 8 8 -t @@@@%%%% -o wordlist.lst
```

The command above creates a file named **wordlist.lst** as specified by the switch **-o**. The first **8** defines the minimum quantity of charachters in every word, so the second **8** defines the maximum.

The **@** and the **%** are crunch special charachters that are substituted respectively by lowercase letters and numbers.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but the example does not give randomized numbers or letters. Examples of what I want: abcd1234 fjsa2942 skjd9232

Comment: I think you can't do it only with crunch.

Comment: The output could be randomized with `shuf`, but then one should also wait for the whole `crunch` command to end. Also I suggest to be careful when saving the output to the disk (~38 GB).

Comment: Well what would create the desired output of my exmaple?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the possibility to test the command before! Let's try this `crunch 8 8 -t  @@@@%%%% | perl -ne 'print unless /([a-z0-9]).*\1/' > wordlist.lst`